# Where is the mapbox studio repository?

Tags: mapbox

I could only find the classic one https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-studio-classic

I would like to issue a sprite feature request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a feature request for Mapbox Studio, please use the contact form at [mapbox.com/contact](https://www.mapbox.com/contact).

Comment: Can you make a github repository instead please, its just very convenient to see a overview of issues you are already working on or others have already addressed. You dont have to include the source code just a empty repository will be fine with a readme for more contact information if needed. It has also the benefit to reference them in my own projects or one of the other mapbox repositories, making collaborating allot more effective.